# Why is there a trend towards cantilevered rear wheels in recent motorcycle designs?

Tags: motorcycle, suspension

In looking at the new motorcycle designs that are coming out in roughly the last decade or so, there seems to be a trend towards the cantilevered rear wheel. My question is what are the advantages to this design?

Here's an example of an older, traditional design:

[image: Honda CB750]

And here is a modern cantilevered rear wheel design:

[image: Modern rear wheel design]

Note that on the older design there is a shock mounted on a rear suspension arm to a point just below the rider. On the modern design that shock or support are not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The design nomenclature in the motorcycling community is called '[Mono-shocks](https://www.google.com/search?q=motorcycle%20mono%20shocks&biw=1344&bih=740&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi19M6-qJTMAhUB_WMKHYaaBtIQsAQIIw)'**

Mono-shocks are essentially a design extension of the desire to reduce unsprung weight.  Unsprung weight is merely the weight of the suspension that IS NOT carried by the springs.  In other words, it's the weight the springs need to get back on the ground when and undulation compresses the system while driving.

There are many different configurations of this feature over time.  Various manufacturers named their suspension solutions.  For example, Suzuki during the 80's and early 90's called their mono-shock system the *Full Floater* suspension.  The first road example in their line-up with this configuration was the [1983 GS750E and ES](https://www.google.com/search?q=1983%20suzuki%20gs750es&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLjI2_rJTMAhVJ-2MKHWy5DEgQsAQIHA&biw=1344&bih=740) models.  This design was further popularized by it's use in Grand Prix Motorcycle Road Racing.

**Notice how the lower shock eye 'floats' in the linkage.**

[image]

Other manufacturers have various configurations, the *Full Floater* is simply an example of one of them.

**Benefits**

There are multiple benefits to the mono-shock configuration.

- Frame Reduction - The rear frame component beneath the rider can become a bolt on component and only needs to support the riders weight.  It no long requires the strength and rigidity required to deal with the forces traveling through the swingarm from the road.
- Reduced Sprung Weight - The reduction in frame components due to the differences in shock location and mounting can greatly reduce chassis sprung weight.
- Tuning Flexibility - The shock compression ratio can be tuned on floating configurations with various linkage lengths.
- Uniformity of Compression - A single shock is in charge of the rate of compression using various dampening and spring rate configurations.  There is a school of thought in the MC world that believed the dual rear shocks were required to match one another in order to prevent the rear wheel from canting in the swingarm under hard cornering.  If this issue existed, I believe it does, it's no longer a point of contention in the newer configuration of a monoshock.
- Reduced unsprung weight.  A single shock of unsprung weight as opposed to two.

**Trend**

There is not statistical analysis on the subject that I can find but of the entire 2016 Suzuki Motorcycle model lineup of 51 vehicles there are two models that have the legacy dual shock system.  Of the entire 1982 lineup of Suzuki street motorcycles, none of the models had a mono-shock.  So it is a trend with almost all manufacturers that tout modern technology in their model lines.  The dual shock configuration is considered legacy technology and is usually only seen on very low cost, low power models in a manufacturer's lineup.

Comment: Hey, it'd be nice if you could also add the effect of piston travel, heating etc. With mono's you have reduced piston movement.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be difficult to identify a trend without some heavy-duty statistical analysis, but the "cantilevered" rear wheel is all about suspension travel. This design is for off-road bikes, BMX bikes, etc. that need a lot of vertical travel in the rear wheel.

Part of the reason for the need for lots of travel is the need for softer springs. There's an interesting video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGZRairqHNI), about why softer is better, but the idea is that a softer spring can keep the wheel in contact with the ground much longer than a stiffer spring. More contact with the ground is obviously better, but the softer spring requires more vertical travel distance.

As to "why is there a trend," I'm not sure there's an answer. It may be that there's a manufacturing or engineering reason that they are preferable, but I doubt it. It may just be that's the kind of bike you like to look for ;-)

Comment: Wow... after more research, this is probably not even remotely true... Oh well.